# content position issue using headerLargeTitle from react navigation native stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to use [headerLargeTitle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerlargetitle) feature from **react-navigation/native-stack**, but I'm having some issues with the content position.

### The problem: The content is not centered

Here are some examples with `headerTransparent: true` and with the default white color, as you can notice part of the content container is behind the header (the light salmon-colored box)

[image]
[image]

### What I've tried

#### Wrap the content with a scrollable view

According to the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerlargetitle) you can wrap the content with a `scrollView` or `flatList` with the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"` prop defined, what this does is to move the content by adding a content insets, this brings other problems since it makes the content scrollable and doesn't solve the centering problem either.

[image]

#### Use an extra `<SafeAreaView />`

Wrap my content in a `<SafeAreaView />` and put inside an aditional `<SafeAreaView />`, this seems to solve the problem on the **iPhon13** but on smaller devices like the **iPhone8**(where the size of the safe area changes), this doesn't work. here is an example code:

```js
<SafeAreaVie>
  <SafeAreaView />
  <View>
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

#### What I want

I want to use `headerLargeTitle` feature and the content to start just below the header without wrapping the content with `ScrollView` with `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"`.

**NOTE**: here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@cris0501/headerlargetitle-issue) with the example code used in the question

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I just fixed this with adding marginTop: useHeaderHeight() to the content itself but I want more proper solution for this

Comment: I found a different solution, to the height that you get with `useHeaderHeight()` you can add `52`, where it comes from in `52`?, I got it with the element inspector and reviewed the react-navigation source code, and I note that is a constant value so there is no error if you use it as static value, so I create this hook: `export const useFatHeaderHeight = () => {
  const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
  const BOTTOM_HEADER_HEIGHT = 52;
  const fatHeaderHeight = headerHeight + BOTTOM_HEADER_HEIGHT;

  if (isIOS()) {
    return fatHeaderHeight;
  }

  return 0;
}; `